# Nvidia driver does not load even with Secure Boot disabled

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, secure-boot

I have a Kubuntu 18.04 installed and I've been playing around with my Nvidia driver (I confess). By that, I mean that I had Nvidia driver 430 installed and working completely. But then since I could not make Nvidia PRIME work, I uninstalled the driver and reinstalled it. I believe I've done that more than a couple of times (maybe one too many).

Anyways, the last time I installed the driver, it worked just like any time before that. But then after a reboot, the resolution is now locked on something pretty low. After some searching online, I found that it might mean that the driver is not properly loaded. And I need to disable the secure boot. But then, I remembered that I had done this before and in fact each time I boot the system, before grub menu, it says `Booting in insecure mode`. Still, I followed the instructions on [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules) but of course, you cannot disable something that is already disabled!

To give you a little bit more information:

```
$ sudo lshw -c display
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Does anyone know how to install my Nvidia driver properly?

Comment: It is very hard to tell what you broke while "playing" with the driver. Reinstall the system looks the easiest way to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. I'm not sure if it helps with anyone else but it helped me. Apparently, I had switched to my `intel` driver using the `prime-select` command. So, all I needed to do was to switch back to `nvidia`:

```
sudo prime-select nvidia
```

But why I still had a video output from my Nvidia card and not my Intel card, is an issue for another post.